# how JVM perform null check on an object internally

Tags: java, jvm

how JVM perform null check on an object internally.
suppose some method return an object .how does java internally perform this null check ?

```
Parent parent=Test.getParent();
if(parent!=null){
    A a=parent.getAObject();`enter code here`
    if(a!=null){
        B b=a.getBObject();
    }
}
```

Comment: by any chance you meant compiler instead of JVM?

Comment: ```null``` is just a dedicated pointer, it compares the reference to that pointer. It's about the same as comparing integers.

Comment: @jorn how do jvm know current value is null, if yes than how its decide to throw null pointer exception

Comment: It isn't clear what kind of an answer you're looking for here. `null` is a special value, typically but not necessarily zero, that is distinct from all possible values of references to objects. All the JVM has to do is test for that value, whatever it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of Java code it is much the same as

```
if (x == null) throw new NullPointerException();
x.useX();
```

However, when optimise to native code there is a number of tricks the CPU uses such as

- branch prediction, a branch which is almost never taken can be skipped and effectively checked in parallel.
- the zero page can be unmapped, leading to a segmentation fault when used. I.e. this results in no code inlined but the signal handler can work out which line of code trigger the segmentation fault and cause it to throw a NullPointerException instead.
- anaylsis at runtime can determine a field cannot be null, e.g. because of an explicit check for `null` or because it was used more than once in code. This means a check on each access is not required.

Comment: The 3rd bullet should be “by applying method inlining and code flow analysis, the result of the test may be predicted before the native code is emitted, so that no test is necessary”…